# Suddenly the Form.Shown event doesn't fire anymore

Tags: vb.net

I have a vb.net 2013 project.

I have a form with a lot's of controls. Everything was working perfectly.

But at some point , I don't know what I have done , but the Form.Shown event doesn't fire anymore. The form is open correctly and everything works , except that Event.

I delete and recreated again this event , but doesn't work.

what may be the cause and what I should do to fix this ?

Thank you !

**Updated**

I found that the cause of the problem is this line of code in Load event :

```
Application.AddMessageFilter(filter1)
```

where filter1 is a IMessageFilter.

This filter prevent users clicking on a specific form's area when a condition is true. When I remove this line of code , the shown event is fired.

But what has to do this with a form shown ???!!! And why on other forms ( where I have also exactly this line of code ) everything is working perfectly ?

Comment: Start with showing what you have done would be a start.

Comment: I found that the cause of the problem is this line of code in Load event  : Application.AddMessageFilter(filter1)
where filter1 is a IMessageFilter. This filter prevent users clicking on a specific form;s area when a condition is true.
When I remove this line of code , the shown event is fired. But what has to do this with a form shown ???!!!
And why on other forms ( where I have also exactly this line of code )  everything is working perfectly ?

Comment: Maybe in other forms, you are proccessing the Windows Messages correctly on WndProc method.  Check that

Comment: Please update your question with what you have put in  your comment.  It should be part of the question.

Comment: @Chris  I have updated.Thank you !

Comment: sorry , can I know why I have a - 1 vote ? It's better to know what It's wrong with this question in order to not make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 1):

Might be worth checking the first line of the procedure at the Handles part, there should be something after it like Private Sub txtBox1_TextChanged(events......) Handles txtBox1.TextChanged

Not sure exactly what it would be for that event but something like

```
Handles Me.Shown
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: No , this has nothing to do with problem , because is as should to be , and it's the same for all forms. I have problem only on one of them.